# Android Developer Options causing the app to work improperly

Tags: android

I have created an android app for the **Portuguese (Brasil)**. This is one of my client's app. The client is getting feedback from the app users that they are not able to use the app properly or it goes back to start screen when they click on the button to import a contact from the Phonebook.
i.e. In the app, there are various places where I start the activity to get the result.
`startActivityForResult(intent, requestCode);`
Generally, I'm doing this from Fragments. And to pass the result from Activity to its Fragment, I'm doing like following:

```
@Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        if (getSupportFragmentManager() != null) {
            Fragment fragment = getFragment();
            if (fragment != null)
                fragment.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        }
    }
```

So to check this problem We asked some of the users to check if they have **Developer options** enabled on their device. And Yes, they have it enabled on their devices. So we asked them to disable this and try the app and believe me it works.

I also have this option enabled on my device to test the app (Debugging) and I haven't faced any problem like this while using the app.

I don't understand this issue and I need to find the appropriate solution.
So I need your help to solve this problem.

Looking for the positive responses.

Thanks.

Comment: On your device, in Developer Options, toggle on "Don't keep activities", then see if you can reproduce the problem. If you can, drop a breakpoint in `onActivityResult()` and see if `getFragment()` is returning `null`.

Comment: @CommonsWare Yes, I'm able to reproduce the issue. And `getFragment()` is `not null`. It is the instance of first added Fragment.

Comment: OK, so that indicates that your code snippet is not the direct source of the issue. Hopefully, now that you can reproduce the problem, you can find out its cause. "Don't keep activities" is rather artificial, and it may be that you find that the cause would never be encountered without "Don't keep activities" enabled. But we use "don't keep activities" to help identify problems with things like configuration changes, and configuration changes are fairly commonplace. So, ideally, you get your app to survive when used with "Don't keep activities", for better robustness overall.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, after a very long time, the issue is resolved.
When we have **Don't keep Activities** option enabled on the device and as soon as you leave the activity, it gets destroyed. 
And in the onCreate, I was adding the initial fragment again.

But now I have added a check of

```
if(savedInstanceState == null)
 // initial fragment here
else
 // nothing to do
```

This check resolved the issue in my app. Hope it helps the others too.

Answer (score 0):

Try fragment context instead of getActivity() as you are starting activity from the fragment and result should be returnned to fragment.

```
Intent intent=new Intent(fragment.getContext(), Activity.class) 
fragment.startActivityForResult(intent,REQUEST_CODE);
```